# Can my PC and a dedicated server be on the same machine?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, multi-boot

If I had a 500 GB SSD and a 1 TB HDD installed on one computer, could I use the 1 TB HDD as a dedicated server using Linux Mint or Ubuntu Server Edition as the OS?

Then on my 500 GB SSD I could install my Windows 7 basically setting up a dual-boot.  But would the server still be active (like me and others can still access it), while I'm on my other OS or would I have to setup a virtual machine within windows to run it and still keep the Linux Mint/Ubuntu Server edition in the 1 TB HDD?

Comment: Please edit and delete some of the questions inside your post here and ask questions about the separate topics in separate questions. A question should contain only one topic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to set up a VM to run two operating systems at the same time. A computer can only run a single primary OS at once; anything else has to be on a virtual machine.

Comment: Would I still be able to keep the linux in the 1tb HDD using the virual Machine and windows 7 on the 500gb SSD?

Comment: I'm not absolutely sure, but you might want to check [this](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/784138-howto-boot-existing-ubuntu-partition-using-virtualbox-inside-windows/) out.

Comment: Virtual machines can be assigned to physical disks, so you would be able to have that set up

Answer (score 0):

The term dedicated server implies a virtual or physical machine that is set aside to solely run a set of services. The combination of purposes *workstation* and *server* would make the server non-dedicated.

***A dedicated server may not be on the same machine as a workstation.***

You could put a *dedicated game server* (such as HLDS) on a workstation without any trouble, but it would not be dedicated in the strict sense of the word.